# Does $\overline{A}$ be dense-in-itselft implies A is dense-in-itselft?

Tags: general-topology

Let ($X, τ$) ve a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ we say that $A$ is dense-in-itselft if $A \subseteq A'$ where $A'$ denotes the set of acumulation points of A.
If $\overline{A}$ is dense-in-itselft then A is dense-in-itselft?
I think yes but I have no idea of how to proof it or any counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: Yes, provided $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$.

Fix $x\in A$ and $U\in\tau$ with $x\in U$. By assumption, $x\in \overline A\subset (\overline  A)'$, so there is some $y\in \overline A$ with $y\in U$ and $y\neq x$. By assumption, there is some $V\in \tau$ with $y\in V$ and $x\not \in  V$. Now $y\in \overline A$ and $y\in V\cap U$, so there is some $z\in A$ with $z\in V\cap U$. Since $x\not \in V$, we can infer that $z\neq x$.

But then every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains  a point of $A$ different from $x$. Therefore, $x\in A'$.

Answer (score 3):

The restiction to $T_1$ spaces is in general necessary.

Let $S=\{0,1\}$ with the topology $\{\varnothing,\{0\},S\}$, let $[0,1]$ have its usual topology, let $Y=[0,1]\times S$ have the product topology, and let $X=Y\setminus\{\langle0,1\rangle\}$. Let

$$A=\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\cup\big((0,1]\times\{1\}\big)\,;$$

then $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is an isolated point of $A$, so $A$ is not dense-in-itself, but $\operatorname{cl}A=X$, which has no isolated points and is therefore dense-in-itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $X=\{1,2\}$ with $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$. Then, $\{1\}'=\{2\}$ and $\overline{\{1\}}=X=X'$.

Your claim is true for T1 spaces.
If $X$ is T1 and $\overline{A}'\subseteq\overline A$, let $a\in A$ and let $U\ni a$ be open. Since $a\in\overline A$, there is some $b\in \overline A\cap U$ such that $b\ne a$. Now, consider and open set $V$ suc that $b\in V$ and $a\notin V$. Since $b\in\overline A$ and $b\in U\cap V$, there is some $a'\in A\cap U\cap V$. Therefore $a'\in A\cap U\setminus\{a\}$.